# Verify outlook opened using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to test web application.

I want to test "Send email" button.

> When I select some text on the screen and click on the button it opens
>   up Outlook Message with the selected text as the message of the email.

How can I verify the Outlook was opened and message contains that text and how can I close the outlook after the test is done?

Comment: Selenium automates web applications, nothing else, so this may be possible but not using Selenium. Is the email stored before it is sent? As in, stored in the database? Can you get the email sent to an easier place to go to such as Gmail or Yahoo? Have you searched what API's and libraries exist to help automate Outlook in your language?

Comment: EMails are not stored. It opens up the outlook email and we have to manually hit send to send it. Anyways I wanted to know whether it will work or not with selenium. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the Outlook WebApp, then simple. Store the text you want as a variable getting the text of what you want.  Click the compose button, and setText of whatever the variable was.

Comment: You probably are testing a mailto: link which opens the default mail program(in your case outlook) and pre-populates the message body. Why?? You should just test if you capture the selection correctly, and that the mailto link is well formed based on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the help of Java. Can write a method like this... `Evalue` is the string that you are capturing from the WebElement using `getText()`

```
public static String getClipboard(String Evalue)
        throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    Thread.sleep(30000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(30000);

    Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
            .getContents(null);
    try {
        if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            String wintext = (String) t
                    .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

        System.out.println("wintext" + wintext);

            if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(wintext.trim())) {
                System.out.println("text is identical");

            } else {
                System.out.println("text is identical");
                System.out.println(wintext);
            }
            // return text.trim();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```